# plot one regression line per figure from nested data coeficients

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I have added some plotting code to a nested tibble to plot two lines, one with goem_smooth and the second with geom_abline using regression coefficients (intent is one smoothed line and one regression line for each row record in the nested tibble).

The line from geo_smooth works correctly (unique smoothing line for each set of data in the row record). But the geom_abline adds one regression line for each record to every figure. In this case I have 66 row records so each figure is plotting with 66 different regression lines. Here is the code that adds the gg code to the nested tibble:

```
> by_watershed_figs
# A tibble: 66 x 7
   loc_major_basin watershed_data censmodel watershed_pvalue watershed_intercept watershed_slope `map(...)`
             <int> <list> <list> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>    
 1 7080 <tibble [2,562 x 18]>  <S3: survreg> 0. -171. 0.867 <S3: gg>  
 2 7040 <tibble [12,512 x 18]> <S3: survreg> 0. -719. 0.379 <S3: gg>  
 3 7010 <tibble [3,669 x 18]> <S3: survreg> 0. -233. .18  <S3: gg>  
 4 9020 <tibble [839 x 18]> <S3: survreg> 0. -425. 2.13  <S3: gg>  
 5 9021 <tibble [1,658 x 18]> <S3: survreg> 0. 933. -.46 <S3: gg>  
 6 9022 <tibble [1,10 x 18]> <S3: survreg> 1.44e -258. .30  <S3: gg>  
 7 7030 <tibble [3,619 x 18]> <S3: survreg> 0. -2499. 1.27  <S3: gg>  
 8 4010 <tibble [857 x 18]> <S3: survreg> 0. 3496. -.71  <S3: gg>  
 9 7041 <tibble [11,353 x 18]> <S3: survreg> 0. -995. .512 <S3: gg>  
10 7020 <tibble [8,076 x 18]> <S3: survreg> 2.08 -329. .185 <S3: gg>  
# ... with 56 more rows
> # make some figures
```

And here is the code that adds plotting code to the nested tibble

```
# make some figures
by_watershed_figs <- by_watershed_full %>% 
  mutate(
    map(watershed_data, ~ ggplot(., aes(x = year, y = combined_stube_conv100_conv60)) + 
          geom_point(alpha = 0.4, size = 0.25) + 
          labs(x = 'Year', 
               y = 'Clarity (cm)',
               title = 'Minnesota stream Secchi tube measures',
               subtitle = loc_major_basin) + 
          ylim(0, 130) +
          geom_smooth(se = TRUE, color = 'purple') +
          geom_abline(intercept = watershed_intercept, slope = watershed_slope, color = 'orange')
    )
  )
```

In testing I was able to get a single line buy indexing the first row record by using [[[1]] like this:

```
 geom_abline(intercept = watershed_intercept[[1]], slope = watershed_slope[[1]], color = 'orange')
```

But as expected that adds a regression like for first record's data to all 66 figures and not from the data for each row record.

Add reproducible example with dummy data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(gam)
library(broom)
library(purrr)

tb <- structure(list(
  dt = structure(c(
    14245, 14276, 14304, 14335, 14365,
    14396, 14426, 14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 14610, 14641,
    14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914,
    14944, 14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187,
    15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461,
    15492, 15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 15737,
    15765, 15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 14245, 14276,
    14304, 14335, 14365, 14396, 14426, 14457, 14488, 14518, 14549,
    14579, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822,
    14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095,
    15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371,
    15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645,
    15675, 15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918,
    15949
  ), class = "Date"),
  averagetemperature = c(
    -4.299, 1.454, 4.808, 7.623, 12.627, 17.305, 19.792, 21.724,
    19.502, 11.22, 10.261, 1.563, -0.595, 0.771, 6.489, 10.935,
    13.803, 19.055, 24.106, 24.948, 19.229, 14.582, 8.539, -0.071,
    -1.582, 0.276, 3.474, 7.383, 12.133, 18.011, 24.412, 23.414,
    18.331, 13.837, 9.555, 5.327, 2.67, 3.698, 12.145, 8.383, 14.956,
    19.532, 25.909, 22.778, 18.693, 12.229, 7.27, 5.592, 1.056, -0.509,
    1.323, 6.644, 13.734, 17.913, 21.914, 22.23, 19.977, -5.36, -0.372,
    3.579, 10.478, 15.447, 19.058, 21.103, 22.769, 17.043, 10.364, 8.217,
    -0.624, -2.359, -1.456, 6.715, 12.076, 17.119, 21.943, 24.789,
    22.67, 19.172, 11.911, 5.876, -2.165, -4.463, -1.244, 3.474,
    10.555, 16.917, 21.032, 24.564, 22.13, 19.301, 12.001, 8.013,
    2.987, -0.0410000000000004, 2.185, 8.734, 10.324, 17.779, 20.165,
    24.479, 22.731, 18.177, 12.436, 4.103, 2.586, -0.968, -1.365,
    2.518, 9.723, 15.544, 20.892, 24.722, 21.001, 17.408
  ),
  averagetemperatureuncertainty = c(
    0.336,
    0.328, 0.247, 0.348, 0.396, 0.554, 0.481, 0.315, 0.225, 0.162,
    0.372, 0.348, 0.348, 0.364, 0.357, 0.538, 0.892, 0.33, 0.325,
    0.36, 0.322, 0.241, 0.307, 0.326, 0.522, 0.446, 0.279, 0.265,
    0.733, 0.773, 0.255, 0.404, 0.173, 0.154, 0.334, 0.483, 0.727,
    0.567, 0.369, 0.347, 0.835, 0.519, 0.516, 0.42, 0.329, 0.333,
    0.263, 0.537, 0.528, 0.473, 0.275, 0.462, 0.863, 0.669, 0.322,
    0.373, 1.033, 0.288, 0.214, 0.14, 0.259, 0.267, 0.452, 0.348,
    0.277, 0.22, 0.153, 0.181, 0.228, 0.314, 0.319, 0.235, 0.135,
    0.2, 0.387, 0.28, 0.257, 0.165, 0.154, 0.174, 0.436, 0.355, 0.33,
    0.167, 0.222, 0.312, 0.42, 0.438, 0.163, 0.16, 0.23, 0.298, 0.466,
    0.493, 0.253, 0.276, 0.258, 0.301, 0.39, 0.403, 0.224, 0.269,
    0.344, 0.298, 0.257, 0.29, 0.241, 0.255, 0.355, 0.281, 0.273,
    0.279, 0.323, 1.048
  ), city = c(
    "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
    "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
    "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
    "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
    "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
    "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
    "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
    "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
    "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
    "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
    "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York",
    "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York",
    "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York",
    "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York",
    "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York",
    "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York",
    "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York",
    "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York",
    "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York",
    "New York", "New York", "New York"
  ), country = c(
    "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
    "United States"
  ), latitude = c(
    "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N",
    "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N",
    "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N",
    "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N",
    "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N",
    "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N",
    "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N",
    "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N",
    "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "40.99N", "40.99N",
    "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N",
    "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N",
    "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N",
    "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N",
    "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N",
    "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N",
    "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N",
    "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N"
  ),
  longitude = c(
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W",
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W",
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W",
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W",
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W",
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W",
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W",
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W",
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W",
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "74.56W", "74.56W",
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W",
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W",
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W",
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W",
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W",
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W",
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W",
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W",
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W",
    "74.56W"
  )
), row.names = c(NA, -114L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
  dt = structure(list(
    format = ""
  ), class = c("collector_date", "collector")),
  AverageTemperature = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), AverageTemperatureUncertainty = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), City = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  )), Country = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  )), Latitude = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  )), Longitude = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  ))
), default = structure(list(), class = c(
  "collector_guess",
  "collector"
))), class = "col_spec"))

# Load the data from dput() and take a look
summary(tb)
str(tb)
names(tb)

# make lowercasae
tb <- rename_all(tb, tolower)
names(tb)

# nest data, 100 major cities
by_city_month <- tb %>% 
  filter(year(dt) >= 1900) %>%
  mutate(month = month(dt)) %>%
  mutate(yr1900 = year(dt) - 1900) %>%
  group_by(city, country, month) %>%
  nest()

by_city_month

# define function for linear model
city_model_lm <- function(df) {
  lm(averagetemperature ~ yr1900, data = df)
}

# create columns for the models
cmodels <- by_city_month %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, city_model_lm)
  )

# add tidy and glance to list
cmodels <- cmodels %>% 
  mutate(tidy = map(model, tidy),
         glance = map(model, glance)
         )

# unnest glance list
cmodels_g <- cmodels %>%
  unnest(glance) %>%
  select(city, country, month, data, model, p.value)
cmodels_g

# unnest and spread the tidy list [4x7] into 28 rows for each watershed
cmodels_t <- cmodels %>%
  unnest(tidy) %>%
  select(city, country, month, term, estimate) %>%
  spread(key = term, value = estimate) %>%
  select(city, country, month, `(Intercept)`, yr1900)
cmodels_t

# join tables to get pvalues and slopes in a single table, rename variables to
# make jointing with stream table easier to follow
cmodels_all <- left_join(cmodels_g, cmodels_t) %>%
  rename(intercept = `(Intercept)`, slope = yr1900)
cmodels_all

# add ggplot to list
cmodels_figs <- cmodels_all %>%
  mutate(
    map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(x = yr1900, y = averagetemperature)) +
          geom_point() +
          ylab('Average Temperature') +
          xlab('Years past 1900') +
          geom_smooth(se = TRUE, color = 'purple') +
          geom_abline(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, color = 'orange') +
          ggtitle(label = city, subtitle = month)
    )
  ) %>%
  rename(plots =`map(...)`)

# draw figures
cmodels_figs$plots
```

Comment: Maybe try and add a second `geom_smooth()` instead of `geom_abline()`, specifying a `lm` model: `+ geom_smooth(method='lm')`, can't test this because your example is not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try. The issue is that slope and intercept are coming from a tobit regression. Sorry for the lack of reproducibility, but the whole script and data are hard to coral.

Comment: added some code to make the problem reproducable